# Why can't i add any paragraph at the center of the page in HTML?

Tags: css, html

I just started developing a personal homepage for my own. Everything went well until I wanted to write text outside the menu border and header (that means somehow center of the page). If I add any paragraph in HTML file, it actually moves the menu items & Header and then places the text. I don't know what's going wrong.

```
        <!--
    All the html code will go in this file. This is the main core file of any website.
    -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <html lang="en">
    <html charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to Fatah's world!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main_design.css"/>

    <!--<img src="bricks.JPG" alt="blue bricks" width="300" height="1000">-->
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>This is a paragraph i am trying to place in my page, but it doesn't stay in the accurate position.</p>

    <h1 id="style_header">Welcome to my green world!</h1></div>


    <div id="menu_area" >

    <div id="home">HOME</div><br /><br /><br /> 
    <div id="about_me">ABOUT ME</div><br /><br /> <br />
    <div id="gallery">GALLERY</div><br /><br /> <br />
    <div id="contact_me">CONTACT ME</div><br /><br /> <br />
    <div id="my_diary">MY DIARY</div><br /><br /> <br />
    <div id="blog">BLOG</div><br /><br /> <br />

    </div>

    <div id="footer">Developed by Jabir Al Fatah</div>

   </body>



        /*
    All the css properties will go in this file. CSS properties design the site to look it prettier.
    */
    #style_header{
    background-color:blue;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    margin:-8px;
    border:4px solid red;

    }

    #paragraph{
    text-align:center;

    }

    #menu_area{
    border:4px solid red;
    margin:-8px;
    background-color:#FFD700;
    padding-top:30px;
    margin-top:4px;
    height:600px;
    width:150px;


    }
    body{
    background-image:url(green.JPG);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

    #footer{
    background-color:blue;
    margin:-8px;
    border:2px solid red;

    text-align:center;

    }

    #home{
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
    }

    #about_me{
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
    }
    #gallery{
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
    }
    #contact_me{
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
    }
    #my_diary{
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
    }
    #blog{
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
    }
   </html>
```

Comment: `#paragraph`...you have no element with an ID of 'paragraph'. To select the paragraph use just `p`.

Comment: Also, don't use break tags for spacing...use margins and padding.

Comment: CSS should be inside `<style>.....</style>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add the `p` before your `header` and `menu-area`, it will appear before `header` and `menu-area`, if you want it to appear after `header` and `menu-area`, add it after them

```
<h1 id="style_header">Welcome to my green world!</h1></div>


<div id="menu_area" >

<div id="home">HOME</div><br /><br /><br /> 
<div id="about_me">ABOUT ME</div><br /><br /> <br />
<div id="gallery">GALLERY</div><br /><br /> <br />
<div id="contact_me">CONTACT ME</div><br /><br /> <br />
<div id="my_diary">MY DIARY</div><br /><br /> <br />
<div id="blog">BLOG</div><br /><br /> <br />

</div>

<p>This is a paragraph i am trying to place in my page, but it doesn't stay in the accurate position.</p>

<div id="footer">Developed by Jabir Al Fatah</div>
```

P.S: if you want your `p` to appear next to `menu-area` and not below it, change `display` of `menu-area` and `p` to `inline-block`

something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCmg8/

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCmg8/1/

Comment: I want to add p next to the menu area, not below it. ok so can u be more specific about display of menu area and inline block. I should  set the display for what? and inline-block?

Comment: gaurav5430, it still very inaccurate. It does not set the paragraph just below the header and next to menu area. what id does is push the menu area little bit up and place the text under it. I guess something is wrong with CSS styling.